# How in Python & PyQt5 load contents of a tab from another class?

Tags: python, pyqt5

There is a class MainWindow, which has a bar with tabs. One of the tabs create FactorsTab class, located in FactorsTabWidget.py file.

at startup crashes:

> line 13, in **init** self.table =
> QtGui.QStandardItemModel(parent=self.frame_factors) AttributeError:
> 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'QStandardItemModel'
>
> line 13 in file FactorsTabWidget.py: self.table = > QtGui.QStandardItemModel(parent=self.frame_factors)

How to generate the contents of a tab from another class?

**file main.py**

```
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        factors_tab = FactorsTabWidget.FactorsTab()
        self.tabs = QtWidgets.QTabWidget()
        self.tabs.addTab(factors_tab, "Factors")
```

**file FactorsTabWidget.py**

```
class FactorsTab(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent=None)
        self.frame_factors = QtWidgets.QTableView()
        self.table = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(parent=self.frame_factors)
        self.lst1 = ['Дискета', 'Бумага для принтера', 'Барабан для принтера']
        self.lst2 = ["10", "3", "10452048"]
        for row in range(0, 3):
            item1 = QtGui.QStandardItem(self.lst1[row])
            item2 = QtGui.QStandardItem(self.lst2[row])
            self.table.appendRow([item1, item2])
        self.table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Factor Name', 'Кол-во'])
        self.frame_factors.setModel(self.table)
```

Comment: message means you have `QtGui == None` , maybe you set `QtGui = None` or `QtGui = something` in some place.

Answer (score 1):

1. I have changed parent init in class created fo make tab 'code from `QtWidgets.QTableView.__init__(self, parent=None) toQtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent=None)'`
2. in string `QtGui.QStandardItemModel` change parameters from `(parent=self.frame_factors)` to `(0, 2)`

everything need to create a table in Tab is create an instance of the widget

work solution:

**file main.py**

```
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.factors_tab = FactorsTab()
        self.table_tab = TableTab()        
        self.box = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.tabs = QtWidgets.QTabWidget()
        self.tabs.addTab(self.factors_tab, "Factors")
        self.tabs.addTab(self.table_tab, "Table of coding factors")        
        self.setCentralWidget(self.tabs)
        self.tabs.setElideMode(QtCore.Qt.ElideLeft)
        self.tabs.setCurrentIndex(0)
        self.tabs.setUsesScrollButtons(True)
        self.tabs.setLayout(self.box)
        self.add_menu()
```

**file FactorsTabWidget.py**

```
class FactorsTab(QtWidgets.QTableView):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QTableView.__init__(self, parent=None)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Select folder, project file name")
        self.vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.label)
        self.frame_factors = QtWidgets.QTableView()
        self.table = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(0, 2)
        self.lst1 = ['it1', 'it2', 'it3']
        self.lst2 = ["10", "3", "10452048"]
        for row in range(0, 3):
            item1 = QtGui.QStandardItem(self.lst1[row])
            item2 = QtGui.QStandardItem(self.lst2[row])
            self.table.appendRow([item1, item2])
        self.table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Factor Name', 'Num'])
        self.frame_factors.setModel(self.table)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.frame_factors)
        self.setLayout(self.vbox)
```

Comment: Explain your solution please

Comment: 1. I have changed parent init in class created fo make tab

'code from QtWidgets.QTableView.__init__(self, parent=None) toQtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent=None)'

2. in string 'QtGui.QStandardItemModel(0, 2)' change parameters

Comment: Edit your answer with what you wrote, please.

Comment: added more details